# regex lookbehind

Tags: regex, powershell, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have a problem with regex lookbehind!

here is my sample text:

```
 href="dermatitis&gt;" "blah blah blah &gt;" href="lichen-planus&gt;"
```

I want to match all `&gt;"`  if and only if there is an `href=` somewhere before it and  yet there is another rule!

The `href=` must be immediately before the previous Quotation mark. (for example the second `&ght;` in text has an `href=` before it but the `href=` is not immediately before the previous Quotation mark and I dont want it to be matched) In my text, there is 3 `&ght;` and  I want first and 3rd one to be matched and the second one not matched based on ruled I described above.

I hope the question is explained enough! and I work on some offline text files and I can use notepad++, powershell or any other suitable engine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _I have a problem with regex lookbehind_ what did you try?

Comment: I have search in regex pages. but it seems lookbehind has some limitations in variable length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ doesn't understand lookbehind, you have to use `\K` instead.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `href="[^"]*\K&gt;(?=")`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
href="[^"]* : search for href=" followed by 0 or more any charcater but "
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
&gt;        : literally &gt;
(?=")       : lookahead, make sure we have '"' after
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 2 years late, but anyway :) Here's solution:

```
$string = 'href="dermatitis&gt;" "blah blah blah &gt;" href="lichen-planus&gt;"'
$value = '&gt;"'
$regex = 'href=".+?(' + $value + ')'
([regex]::matches($string,$regex).groups.value) | ? {$_ -eq $value}
```

Which will return 1st and 3rd values:

```
&gt;"
&gt;"
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way of attacking it through PowerShell that also removes the undesired `&gt;`

```
# Set the regular expression
$regex = '(?<=href\=")(.*?)(?=")'

$sampleText = 'href="dermatitis>&ght;" "blah blah blah >" href="lichen-planus>&ght;"'

# Separate the single line string into 3 entities with " " as the delimiter
$sampleTextSplit = $sampleText.Split(" ")

$sampleMatches = $sampleTextSplit | Where-Object {$_ -match $regex} | Foreach-Object { $_.Replace("&gt;","") }

# Show the results
$sampleMatches
```

This returns two objects:

```
href="dermatitis>"
href="lichen-planus>"
```

Comment: If you copy and paste that code you will find that it does not actually return what you say it does. You have a typo in the sample text.

Comment: Also this solution does not leave the middle &gt in (which is also missing from your sample text btw)

Answer (score -2):

One way you could do it in PowerShell, if your inputs always have spaces between each item:

```
$a = '"href="dermatitis&gt;" "blah blah blah &gt;" href="lichen-planus&gt;"'
$b = $a.Split(" ")
$c = $b | ? { $_ -match 'href="' }
Write-Output $c
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirements stated in the post

Comment: Hi. my work has over 30000 pages and i want to remove &gt from it as i said in question. I think one solution is that I match every  (?<= href \=")(.*?)(?=")  and save it as a variable then remove the &gt; part. but Im not very familiar with powershell coding.

Comment: Your initial post did not mention anything about removing the &gt; strings, but I will see about creating an example for you